# Find a possible path for the excavator such that the fire doesn't burn a total area greater than $13\,\mathrm{km}^2$.

Tags: geometry

A wildfire spreads at a speed of $1\,\mathrm{km/h}$ in all directions.
 When the fire has burnt a circle of radius $1\,\mathrm{km}$, an excavator arrives at the edge of the fire to dig a ditch to stop the spreading of the fire.
 The excavator can proceed at a maximum speed of $14\,\mathrm{km/h}$. Find a possible path for the excavator such that the fire doesn't burn a total area greater than $13\,\mathrm{km}^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A circle of radius $2\,\mathrm{km}$ has area $4\pi\,\mathrm{km}^2\lt13\,\mathrm{km}^2$ and perimeter $4\pi\,\mathrm{km}\lt13\,\mathrm{km}$. Thus the excavator can move out to that radius, travelling $1\,\mathrm{km}$, and then dig a circle of that radius, travelling less than $13\,\mathrm{km}$, thus in total travelling less than $14\,\mathrm{km}$ and thus taking less than a hour, before the fire reaches the circle and thus before it burns a total area of $13\,\mathrm{km}^2$.